# Add the missing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

First of all the scope is a database running in SQL Server 2000 compatibility

I have a custom function for splitting a string

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT 
    @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit),  
    @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
    SELECT ltrim(RTRIM(@name))

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos + 1, LEN(@stringToSplit) - @pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
    SELECT ltrim(RTRIM(@stringToSplit))

 RETURN
END
```

It work very well.

Now to my problem

I have this data:

[image]

Produced by the following SQL:

```
with CTE as
(
  select  '1' CustomerID, 'BCONS1' Code  union 
  select  '1', 'BCONS2'  union 
  select  '2' CustomerID, 'BCONS1' Code  union 
  select  '2', 'BCONS2' 
)
select * 
    from CTE where CustomerID = 1
union 
    select Null, s.Name from dbo.splitstring('ACONS1,ACONS2,ACONS3') S
```

How do I add the "missing" CustomerID to my result?

Comment: What is the value of your  "missing" CustomerID? If it's `1`, why not ` ... select 1, s.Name from dbo.splitstring('ACONS1,ACONS2,ACONS3') S`?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server 2000? According to my Google-Fu CTEs, which you are using above, weren't supported till SQL Server 2005. But really, it's long past time you got onto a supported version; 2000 has been **completely** unsupported for close to **8 years**.

Comment: it's a SQL server 2008 running compatibility mode 2000

Comment: @Zhorov I need to get the Allow bit, for code  ACONS1,ACONS2,ACONS3 for each customer. If one of those codes are missing I need to add them in my select

Comment: @Larnu the server is not my choice

Comment: A database in compatibility level 80 is quite different to an SQL Server 2000 instance, @JensBorrisholt . This explains why the CTE works, as theya re supported in SQL Server 2008. (Though it doesn't change my point about upgrading, as 2008 has been out of support for over 2 years now too. Even if it's not your choice, you should be letting whomever is making said choice know that you are long unsupported now.)

Comment: @Larnu changing  the database server isn't a small task.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt you're using an unsupported database with features that aren't supported by the compatibility mode you used, through a bug that doesn't prevent those unsupported features from compiling. Frankly, this means you're on your own. Few people have worked with SQL Serve 2000, *very* few of those have worked through compatibility modes and I suspect none of them tried to use unsupported features like this.

Comment: *"changing the database server isn't a small task."* I know, I never said it was, I'm in the middle of organising an upgrade from SQL Server 2012 to 2019 at the moment (The Dev server moves over in a couple of weeks), because 2012 has less than a year left of extended support and so it'll all be done *before* that support ends.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt that doesn't justify waiting 15 years to upgrade. This only increases the cost of running the current database and the cost of the unavoidable migration. What you try to do is just a `STRING_SPLIT` in all supported versions

Comment: So what result do you expect? Do we just check the largest value from the top half and count up from there

Comment: I want the null values to be 1 for customer number 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do a cross apply but that is not supported on Compat level 80 either. But we can still force a cartesian product of two tables:

```
with CTE as
(
  select  '1' CustomerID, 'BCONS1' Code  union 
  select  '1', 'BCONS2'  union 
  select  '2' CustomerID, 'BCONS1' Code  union 
  select  '2', 'BCONS2' 
)
select * 
    from CTE where CustomerID = 1
union 
select *
from
   (select distinct 
          CustomerID,  
          s.Value
    FROM CTE 
    , string_split('ACONS1,ACONS2,ACONS3', ',') S
    where CustomerID = 1  -- restrict which rows you need to have added
    ) data
```

Notice I used string_split here instead of your function because [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/14411021110) does't allow me to create functions.

Comment: Thx I'll try that

Comment: That worked just perfect. I'd of course had to change string_split to my own function, since string_split requires Compatibility level 130